# codeigniter bootstrap login form issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I've been doing this for a while to no avail. I'm having an issue with codeigniter bootstrap login. So basically this is what I have:

**login.php - controller**

```
 <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) die();
 class Login extends Main_Controller {

 function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
 }

 public function index()
 { 
  $this->load->view('include/header');
  $this->load->view('login_view');
  $this->load->view('include/footer');
 }

 public function process(){
    // Load the model
    $this->load->model('login_model');
    // Validate the user can login
    $result = $this->login_model->validate();
    // Now we verify the result
    if(! $result){
        // If user did not validate, then show them login page again
        $this->index();
    }else{
        // If user did validate, 
        // Send them to members area
        redirect('home');
    }        
}

}
```

**login_view.php - view**

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-signin" action="<?php echo base_url('login/process');?>" method="post" id="loginForm">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/hms_icon.png'); ?>" />User Login</h2>
    <input type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Username" name="username" id="username">
    <input type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password">
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit" name="login" id="login">Sign in</button> 

    <div id="report"></div>
  </form>
 </div> <!-- /container -->
```

**login_model.php - model**

```
  <?php
 Class Login_model extends CI_Model
{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

public function validate(){
    // grab user input
    $username = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('username'));
    $password = $this->security->xss_clean($this->input->post('password'));

    // Prep the query
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', $password);

    // Run the query
    $query = $this->db->get('users');
    // Let's check if there are any results
    if($query->num_rows == 1)
    {
        // If there is a user, then create session data
        $row = $query->row();
        $data = array(
                '_id' => $row->userid,
                'username' => $row->username,
                'validated' => true
                );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    // If the previous process did not validate
    // then return false.
    return false;
 }
 }
?>
```

I get an error in

```
 <?php echo base_url('login/process');?>
```

Object is not found. What am I missing in here? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error produced by the server?

Comment: The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. page 404

Comment: You really should consider [hashing your passwords](http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) for security sake. I would recommend using [Tank_auth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) for Codeigniter because it does all of these things for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<?php echo base_url('login/process');?>
```

with just

```
'/login/process'
```

Don't forget the leading slash. This is just a guess, because we don't have enough informations provided about your settings.

**EDIT::**

**NOTE:** Read my comment first.

First in your autoload.php load session library. Then modify your process() function in controller like this:

```
public function process(){
   $this->load->model('login_model');
   $result = $this->login_model->validate();
   if(! $result){
       $this->index();
   }else{
      $data = array(
          'username'    => $this->input->post('username'),
          'is_logged_in'    => true
   );

   $this->session->set_userdata($data);
   redirect('home');
}
```

Then in your home.php controller:

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->is_logged_in();
        }

function is_logged_in()
    {
        $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');

        if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
        {
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
```

You need to set the session so the member area knows that user is logged in. You can manage session length and other properties in config.php.

Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Couple of questions. What version of codeigniter are you using? Do you use .htaccess? Are you trying to remove index.php from url? According to your answer to @azngunit81 I believe you have set it up incorrectly.

Comment: <?php echo base_url('index.php/login/process');?> works for me, but it redirects back to the login page :(

Comment: Alright, so in this case you need to use `<?php echo base_url('index.php/login/process');?> ` , but what you are really missing is setting the session. You validate credentials but the next page doesn't know that. See my edit above. I'm posting in next 10 min from this comment

Answer (score 1):

```
 class Login extends Main_Controller {
```

suppose to be

```
 class Login extends CI_Controller {
```

unless you have Main_controller extending CI already

Comment: can you load index.php? basically http://localhost:8888/ - what does Apache/Php log firing?

Comment: can you remove:  <?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) die(); and try again

Answer (score 0):

If your not using .htaccess to remove index.php shown here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html then try this

```
<?php echo base_url('index.php/login/process');?>
```

Comment: is it not validating with this? Instead of redirecting back to login page, test it with an echo of some sort to see.

Comment: I tried to echo out and it worked fine, but when I redirected it to home, it kept coming back to login

Comment: try changing redirect to header("Location: /home.php"); Also check make sure your session variables are stored